# How do i keep divs in particular order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/MUa7P/

In this example a user picks a certain number of clients for an account and is able to remove the clients and add clients.

Each account can have at a max 3 clients.

How do i make it so that on either side the clients are in order of client ID always?

Thanks

Comment: What's with the "client" and "switch" attributes in your HTML? That's not valid markup.

Comment: @wdm, i never said it was valid mockup. this is for an internal app using chromium embedded framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this to sort: http://jsfiddle.net/w2n9a/5/

Answer (score 1):

Solution that goes over the DOM to sort, this relies on everything being ordered on load.

http://jsfiddle.net/compwhizii/vHQGk/12/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the elements in the box it's adding to for it's position and then use the `.insertBefore()` or `.insertAfter()` methods

Comment: I'm on my phone right now so you'll have to wait for someone else to reply, I'll check it out when I get home. But essentially instead of where you append the new element you just need to loop through each div in the destination and compare the ids until you find one that the id of the client that is moving is less than the id of the one in the box and insert the new one before that one.

Comment: @original i am not using `id`s if you see from my code i have an attribute called `client`

Comment: right but you should be able to use `.attr('client')` to get the number (probably have to `parseInt` it)

Comment: you can use .attr('client') to get the values